# Can SSDT deploy SQL server service broker objects?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, deployment

Can SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) deploy sql server broker objects? (So contacts, message types, services, queues and so on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear so. I have not tried these, but the following is the list of items that can be added to an SSDT SQL Server Database Project:

1. Broker Priority
2. Contract
3. Endpoint (ServiceBroker over TCP)
4. Endpoint (SOAP over HTTP)
5. Event Notification
6. Message Type
7. Queue
8. Remote Service Binding
9. Route
10. Service

Comment: Any reason why DacPac deployment skip route changes? Any advance settings needed for SSDT/Data-Tier project?